# How can I transfer login value to another page?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am a newbie in using asp.net with code behind of vb.net I just wanna know on how to see the name of the admin on the POS page. it seems that this code doesn't work??

```
Main.lbl_name.Text = CurName.ToUpper
POS.lbl_cashier.Text = CurName.ToUpper 



Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand
        Dim rdr As SqlDataReader

        cmd1.Connection = cn
        cmd1.Connection.Open()
        cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT * from UserTable WHERE Username ='" & txt_username.Text & "'"
        rdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader

        If rdr.HasRows = True Then
            rdr.Read()
            If txt_username.Text = rdr.Item(0) And txt_password.Text = rdr.Item(3) Then
                CurPos = rdr.Item("Type")
                CurUser = rdr.Item("Username")
                CurName = rdr.Item("EmployeeName")

                If rdr.Item(4) = "ADMINISTRATOR" Then
                    MsgBox("WELCOME! " & rdr.Item(4), MsgBoxStyle.Information)
                    'Main.lbl_name.Text = CurName.ToUpper
                    'POS.lbl_cashier.Text = CurName.ToUpper
                    cmd1.Connection.Close()
                    Response.Redirect("ACESCHOOLSUPPLIES.aspx")
                    'Me.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just access other pages, ASP.NET runtime is ignorant about other pages, you have access to your current page only!

You can use the Session variable to store some data temporarily for current user session, the Session object is available on every ASP.NET Page.

```
  Session("adminname") = CurName
```

On other page where you want to show it you just reload it from Session

```
  Dim NewName = Session("adminname")
```

Answer (score 1):

Take some hidden field and use session.add("username") and store your username or which ever you want and the n retrieve that from your second page.

```
Session.Add("Username",Username);
```

does essentially the same as

```
Session["Username"] = Username;
```

Answer (score 1):

As Alaudo suggested, storing variables in Session state is an option.
For the sake of completeness other options you have are:
Cookies
QueryString
Hidden fields (for POST requests)

The logged on user name is something I personally would not store in Session state or pass around using any of the alternate techniques I mention above.

Looking at your code it seems you are trying to authenticate some credentials (user name/password).
I recommend you look at MemebershipProvider in ASP.NET. Are you familiar with this? You can then easily access the logged in user.