# Master page variables values being lost

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I know this is pretty basic, but why do variables in master pages lose their value in the child pages?

For example if I have

```
[masterpage]

public string userId

... set userId in masterpage


[child page]

Master.userId // userId will always be empty?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this is a stateless paradigm. If you want to maintain those values between post backs you have only a few options:

1. Session State
2. View State
3. Database
4. javascript / hidden values

Comment: @chobo the real mistake is assuming that inheritance means that your variables will still exist between post backs. They don't. That part you can never get away from

Answer (score 3):

Don't use master pages to store information about users -- it won't persist there after the re-load of your page.

If you need to store some user-specific information use the `Session` object to store it.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8126486/376692) is an example.

Answer (score 1):

i'd say try using `Session["userId"]="..."` and in otherpage.aspx =>`Session[userId].ToString()` will get the value